# JPA hierarchy query with restriction on children

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

I'm trying to design rating functional for customers.

Every customer have a single Role.
Every customer could use multiple Applications, but one at a time.

Categories to rate have hierarchy structure and customer should may rate every node of it.

The problematic requirement is that in different applications same customer should see different hierarchy of categories to rate.

So I have following structure in DB to represent requirements:

```
CREATE TABLE T_APPLICATION (
  ID   NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE T_ROLE (
  ID   NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE T_RATING_CATEGORY (
    ID        NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,
    NAME      VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL,
    PARENT_ID NUMBER(19, 0),

    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ID) REFERENCES T_RATING_CATEGORY (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE T_RATING_CATEGORY_2_APP_ROLE (
    CATEGORY_ID    NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,
    ROLE_ID        NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,
    APPLICATION_ID NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (CATEGORY_ID) REFERENCES T_RATING_CATEGORY (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (ROLE_ID) REFERENCES T_ROLE (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (APPLICATION_ID) REFERENCES T_APPLICATION (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,

    PRIMARY KEY (CATEGORY_ID, ROLE_ID, APPLICATION_ID)
);
```

Oracle SQL query to get hierarchy of Categories to rate with restriction by Application and Role looks like this:

```
SELECT c.*, t.* FROM T_RATING_CATEGORY c
JOIN T_RATING_CATEGORY_2_APP_ROLE t on 
    c.id = t.CATEGORY_ID AND
    t.ROLE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM T_ROLE where name = 'SOME_ROLE') AND 
    t.APPLICATION_ID = (SELECT ID FROM T_APPLICATION where name = 'SOME_APPLICATION')
START WITH c.parent_id IS NULL    
CONNECT BY PRIOR c.id = c.parent_id;
```

But I do not understand how to map result to POJOs with preserving of hierarchy.

I know that JPA has no abstraction for hierarchy relation, but I found workaround for that (1):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private RatingCategory parent;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
private Set<RatingCategory> categories;
```

And this represents relation with tie-table (2):

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
    name="T_RATING_CATEGORY_2_APP_ROLE",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY_ID")
)
private Set<RatingCategoryToAppRole> apps2roles;
```

Now due to (1) I can get full hierarchy without restrictions to Application and Role.

```
public List<RatingCategory> getAll(Application app, Role role) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<RatingCategory> query = cb.createQuery(RatingCategory.class);
    Root<RatingCategory> categories = query.from(RatingCategory.class);
    query.select(categories).where(
            cb.isNull(categories.get(RatingCategory_.parent))
        )
    );
    return Optional.ofNullable(em.createQuery(query).getResultList()).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

But it needed every entity of result to be restricted by Application and Role.

As I understand, if I add restriction like this:

```
public List<RatingCategory> getAll(Application app, Role role) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<RatingCategory> query = cb.createQuery(RatingCategory.class);
    Root<RatingCategory> categories = query.from(RatingCategory.class);
    Join<RatingCategory, RatingCategoryToAppRole> apps2Roles = categories.join(RatingCategory_.apps2roles);
    categories.fetch(RatingCategory_.apps2roles);
    query.select(categories).where(
        cb.and(
            cb.isNull(categories.get(RatingCategory_.parent)),
            cb.equal(apps2Roles.get(RatingCategoryToAppRole_.application), app),
            cb.equal(apps2Roles.get(RatingCategoryToAppRole_.role), role)
        )
    );
    return Optional.ofNullable(em.createQuery(query).getResultList()).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
}
```

that will filter just top level of hierarchy and add redundant join.

Is there solution for JPA (EclipseLink) to implement such relations with preservation of hierarchy in POJOs?

Or may be there could be another solution to implement requirements?

Comment: Anyway there is a solution, but I don't like it.

I can make native query with `connect by prior`, map it to plain structure without hierarchy, build from that a map, where `key` would be an `id` of Category and `value` would be new custom non-entity `structure` which in its turn would contain collection of `structure`. Then I can go through map's iterator, find for each value of iteration related `structure` by `parent_id` from same map and add current iteration `value` to found `structure`.

Then it just necessery to get from this map values which have no `parent_id`.

Comment: I realized that no need in `connect by prior` for solution above where result maps to plain structure.